# Enter a string to integer scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to say enter an integer when someone trying to enter a string in this code.

Can you help me?

Here is my code:

```
        import java.util.Scanner;
        public class kl {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                boolean primen = true;
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("Please enter a positive integer that is prime or not : ");
                int ncheck = input.nextInt();
                if (ncheck < 2) {

                    primen = false;

                }
                for (int i = 2; i < ncheck; i++) {
                    if (ncheck % i == 0) {
                        primen = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (primen == true) {
                    System.out.println(ncheck + " is a prime number.");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println(ncheck + " is not a prime number.");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Looks more like Java than JavaScript ?

Comment: Careful with your tags - `javascript` is *not* related to `java`.

Comment: i did it like this

Comment: are you intending to prompt user to enter integer in case he or she enters string

Comment: i am starter in the coding of java and can you explain it easy way. what can i add there ? to give a "please enter a number to see "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find your solution here: [Exception handling](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html), Or use codes below

Here is your complete code:

```
while(true){
System.out.print("Please enter a positive integer that is prime or not : ");
try{
   int i = input.nextInt();
   break;
}catch(InputMismatchException e){
   System.out.print("Wrong type input, pls try again!");
   input.nextLine(); \\ prevent infinite loop
}
```

You can see: I use a Exception handle processor to catch the `InputMismatchException` and print on console the message. You can replace `InputMismatchException`  by Exception. It's largest `Exception` Handler class in java

Comment: thank you a lot for the information it works but it need to


import java.util.InputMismatchException

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you can use with `Scanner`.

- Call `nextInt()` and then catch and handle the `InputMismatchException` that you will get if the next input token isn't an integer.
- Call `hasNextInt()`.  If that returns `true` then call `nextInt()`.

In either case, if you expected an integer and the user entered something else, then neither `nextInt()` or `hasNextInt()` will "consume" the unexpected characters.  So if you want the user to try try again, you need to call `nextLine()` which will read all remaining characters on the line.  You will typically discard them.

For more information on handling exceptions:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html

For more information on using `Scanner`:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html